# Dropdown appends form submit twice

Tags: javascript, html

**EDIT: solved with a count variable and if/else. Not the most elegant but it works. Would be interesting to know why it happens / how it should be solved though so i'll keep this here.**

I have a searchbar with a submit and a dropdown option i am appending to that submit. The submit gets appended twice. I tried using "one" instead of "on" which only returned the first submit. the problem is i need it to only return the second submit or best case prevent the first submit from happening. Currently my url looks like this: "/...?search=test&Item=1&Item=3" and i only want the "&item=3" as the first variable doesn't get updated.

```
   var variableToSend = '';

    $('#selector').on('click',function() {
      variableToSend = $(this).val();
      $('form').append('<input type="hidden" id="yourData" name="Item" value="'+ variableToSend +'"/>');
    });
```

Comment: Please provide a working error case in JSFiddle so that others can look into it and help you out quickly.

Answer (score 0):

you can either remove the button type submit or you can return false for the particular button function or e.prevent.default.

check this link for more details
[How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the appended hidden input and again append the input value in the form. Like this :

```
var variableToSend = '';
$('#selector').on('click',function() {
    variableToSend = $(this).val();
    $('form').find("#yourData").remove();
    $('form').append('<input type="hidden" id="yourData" name="Item" value="'+ variableToSend +'"/>');
});
```